# SQL Server: select data from between a range of dates if dates exist, if not return all data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

`@dateFrom` and `@dateTo` are the variables coming from outside users. They may can put a date in, or choose not to have any range and want to see all data,

```
SELECT  *
FROM tbl
WHERE --
```

I want to implement following conditions

- If `@dateFrom` and `@dateTO` both variable have values, then select data in range
- If `@dateFrom`  has value and `@dateTo` don't, then select data range starting from `@dateFrom` with no ending range.
- If `@dateTo` has value and `@dateFrom` don't, then select data range ending at `@dateTo` with no starting range.
- If non of the variable exist, return all the data.

Comment: What about the table itself? Does it also have a `DateFrom` and `DateTo` columns, or just one date column?

Comment: If there are two columns then there is an additional question: what if the user choose (Dec 21, Dec 25) and you have one row for (Dec 20, Dec 26).

Comment: And what if the date column(s) are nullable? Suppose you have a single nullable date column, and a row where the date is null. Should you return it in all of the search options, or only if both parameters are null, or perhaps if at least one parameter is null? That's also a question to ask for a date range - if The one of the columns is null it's quite easy to understand the record has only one limit, but what if they are both nulls? (usually, this would be avoided declaring the ToDate column as non-nullable or a check constraint allowing only one of the columns to be null for each row)

Comment: My point is, that this question might seem simple (and it might very well be simple), but there are too many details missing to give a good answer that is not based, at least partially, on guesses, or that is not very long so that it would cover all (or at least most) of these potential pitfalls.

Comment: @S. Saleem : You have some answers below to pick! And please tick mark any of your best answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can try `OR` with `AND` and your logic.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE 
    (@dateFrom IS NULL OR DateFrom > @dateFrom) 
AND 
    (@dateTo IS NULL OR DateTo < @dateTo)
```

Comment: This won't work if both the variables are null. As per the question if both variables are null we need to return all the data

Comment: If `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo` are `NULL` it can return all data from tbl. because  contain logic in `()` is `OR`

Comment: didn't notice that

Comment: You have a typo in the last row, and your overlap check is wrong. You should check `from < @to and @from < to` to check for overlapping periods.

Comment: overlap test is still wrong.... see the [overlap tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info) for details.

Comment: It actually works perfect. Its good to put datefrom and dateto in seperate conditions. If we put them together (as others have suggested) it wont work when both variables are null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ISNULL` for this purpose

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE ISNULL(DateFrom,'')=COALESCE(@dateFrom,DateFrom,'') 
    AND ISNULL(DateTo,'')=COALESCE(@dateTo,DateTo,'')
```

Comment: Assuming the DateFrom or DateTo columns are nullable, this will not return any of the rows where one of them is null.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have updated the solution to get the values including the null ones. Can you please check whether is it the right way to do.

Comment: Yes, that will work better, but D-Shih's answer is still better - using functions on columns prevents the database engine from using any indexes that might help the query execution, making them unseargable. Also, you are assuming an exact date range match (which might be correct, we don't know because the OP didn't tell us).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `BETWEEN` Operator with `ISNULL`

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE ISNULL(OrderDate,'') BETWEEN COALESCE(@DateFrom,OrderDate,'') AND COALESCE(@DateTo,OrderDate,'')
```

Edited: Zohar's approach for `NULL` value in Table's Column.
Now it's working perfect!

Comment: Assuming the OrderDate column is nullable, this will not return any of the rows where it's null.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I didn't consider that case!!! 
But Yes, I have just edited my answer by taking reference of Sunny's COALESCE. 
It works perfectly now. 
Thank you for Idea Zohar!

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yes, I did!